# Saltstack Appending variable to itself via for loop

Tags: saltstack

Alright, I'm using salt to manage my grub.conf boot options (most importantly the isolated CPU's) in linux, and have a basic formula to accomplish that:

```
{% set cpu1 = (grains['num_cpus']-1) %}
{% set cpu2 = (grains['num_cpus']-2) %}
{% set cpu3 = (grains['num_cpus']-3) %}
{% set cpu4 = (grains['num_cpus']-4) %}
{% set cpu5 = (grains['num_cpus']-5) %}
{% set cpus = cpu5|string + ',' + cpu4|string + ',' + cpu3|string + ',' + cpu2|string + ',' + cpu1|string %}
{% set bootoptions = 'nosoftlockup isolcpus=' + cpus + ' intel_idle.max_cstate=0 idle=poll processor.max_cstate=0 mce=ignore_ce crashkernel=auto audit=1' %}

insert-options:
  file.replace:
    - name: /boot/grub/grub.conf
    - pattern: (kernel \/vmlinuz-.* quiet)(.*)
    - repl: '\1 {{ bootoptions }}'
```

The only problem with this is that I have to have a manual string of cpu's, which means if say I wanted to add an additional cpu to the list, or remove one, I have to write additional string bits, or remove string bits.

What would be ideal is something along the lines of:

```
{% for x in range(grains['num_cpus']-5,grains['num_cpus']-1) %}
{% set cpus = cpus + ',' + x|string %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried two methods of this, the first was written just as above, that gives me an error that `cpus` isn't defined because the first instance is still trying to set itself to itself, which is understandable.

My second attempt added an out of loop declaration to get things started:

```
{% set cpus = (grains['num_cpus']-6) %}
{% for x in range(grains['num_cpus']-5,grains['num_cpus']-1) %}
{% set cpus = cpus + ',' + x|string %}
{% endfor %}
```

but that ended up making `cpus` **ONLY** contain the value of the out of loop declared value.

Is there a way to make this loop process work?

It would make a huge difference, especially since then I could easily change the offset numbers `(-1,-5)` to pillar items to give me easily customized values for different servers that may need different numbers of isolated CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using Jinja2 for somehow complex tasks. Rather choose a suitable [renderer](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/) for the task to keep the code clear and still readable. You can choose e.g. `Python` language instead of default `Jinja2 + YAML` to get things done:

```
#!py

def run():
  config = {}
  cpus = ''

  for x in range(__grains__['num_cpus'] - 5, __grains__['num_cpus'] - 1 ):
    cpus += ',' + str(x)

  config['echo ' + str(cpus)] = {
    'cmd': [
      'run'
    ]
  }

  return config
```